# Identifying this flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, weeds

What's the name of this flower? We live in the Caribbean.[image]

Answer (score 1):

[rose pink zephyr lily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akjuo.jpg)  Does this look close to your plants?  I LOVE this between the pavers.  Are they flowering continuously or just a part of the year?